# Can't find the private key the example-user-agent creates when creating a new DID

Tags: google-chrome-extension, decentralized-identity, decentralized-identifiers

I am trying to get this project to work: https://didproject.azurewebsites.net/docs/install-extension.html

The user agent states that it generates keys and that the private key is stored on my local pc. I can see the public key in the identities tab but i cannot find the private key anywhere. The user agent is not in the 'extensions' folder of chrome. I need the private key to read/write data to the hub.

By the way tried to create a DID manually but this (https://didproject.azurewebsites.net/docs/registration-test.html) explanation seems to be incomplete/incorrect so i must use the user agent.

Comment: It's probably inside the extension storage. Install Storage Area Explorer and inspect the extension's popup in devtools, in Storage Explorer panel.

Comment: @wOxxOm Looking up the private key with Storage Area explorer worked for me, many thanks!